# Android- Google maps API configuration

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am running an app that displays google map through their API and I am requesting to list places that are categorized as parks and gyms, however it is only listing half at most of what it should be displaying. I was told that the business must first register with google places for it to appear in the search results. But then why are those business in the google maps app? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [They change the filter/algorithm](https://searchengineland.com/google-filtering-business-local-search-results-258044)

Comment: If i am not clear on anything or you have a question, please ask me, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks lloyd, i will look into this

Comment: Places API doesn't guarantee all possible results. Typically it's prominent places and not more than 60 in total.